# Hard Refresh Facebook App on Login Authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I am working on getting validation from Facebook users to access their basic information on the app I'm building. I am using the PHP SDK and the Javascript SDK. The Javascript is to call up the login screen and the PHP is to then take the data and store it in a MySQL table to use around the app.

It's an app where you can vote on things and I have it set so the 'vote' button is a facebook login button if the user is not validated with the app. Everything works great up until the point where they login. It successfully logs them in (on a popup login dialog as normal) but I can't get the parent window to refresh successfully to reflect the changes. Basically the only way to get the user information is if they log in and then manually refresh the app. It then sends all the data correctly. I've tried `location.reload(true);` and I've tried parent window redirects but none of that seems to work.

Below is my Javascript:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(resp) {
        parent.window.location = 'MY_APP_URL';
    });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
  </script>
```

Is there a more effective way to hard refresh the parent window? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if location.reload is not working, you could try

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

it's not the most elegant solution, but it works

Comment: This has the same problem as what I was talking about. It's a multi-page iFrame application if that makes it any different.

Comment: maybe you should use the FB.getLoginStatus function, the response objects has information about the connected user, FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // connected
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // not_authorized
  } else {
    // not_logged_in
  }
 });